# double series, showing what the limit is

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Often I see that the book uses this, without explaining why it holds.

Let $\Sigma_i b_i$ be a convergent series. For each $b_i$ we have that $b_i=\Sigma_jc_{i,j}$. All terms are non-negative!

Now, arrange all the $c_{i,j}$ to $\{c_l\}$ which is a sequence that goes through all the c's.

We then have that:

$\Sigma_ib_i=\Sigma_i[\Sigma_j c_{i,j}]=\Sigma_lc_l$

But how do I actually prove this? The first equality is just notation, but the second is harder. Can someone help? Here is what I got so far:

We have that:

$\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty c_{i,j}=\Sigma_{i=1}^N\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty c_{i,j}+\Sigma_{i=N+1}^\infty\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty c_{i,j}=\Sigma_{i=1}^N\Sigma_{j=1}^{N_{i}}c_{i,j}+\Sigma_{i=1}^N\Sigma_{j=N_i+1}^\infty c_{i,j}+\Sigma_{i=N+1}^\infty\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty c_{i,j}$

We then have that:

$|\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty c_{i,j}-\Sigma_{l=1}^\infty c_l|=|\Sigma_{i=1}^N\Sigma_{j=1}^{N_{i}}c_{i,j}+\Sigma_{i=1}^N\Sigma_{j=N_i+1}^\infty c_{i,j}+\Sigma_{i=N+1}^\infty\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty c_{i,j}-\Sigma_{l=1}^\infty c_l|$.

Now the third term we can get small by increasing N. The second term we get small by increasing all $N_i$ for $i \le N$. We then have a finite amount of elements in the first term. Lets assume for the moment that we know that $\Sigma_{l=1}^\infty c_{i,j}$ converges, the by increasing the N, and $N_i$s sufficiently, we cancel enough elements in the fourth term, by the first term so that everything gets small.

Is this correct? **If this is correct the problem is reduced to showing that $\Sigma_{l=1}^\infty c_{i,j}$ is a convergent series(?), any hints on this?**

Comment: Rearranging the series is OK if it is absolutely convergent.  In particular, if all terms are positive.  But in other cases, your equation can be false.

Comment: @GEdgar All terms are non-negative, sorry I forgot to write it. Can you see how I finish the proof then? It is not only a question about rearrangements. I mean $\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty c_{i,j}$ isn't a rearrangement of the c's, it is a limit value of limit-values.  So it does not follow as I see that we can just rearrange the terms, we have to prove it?

Comment: The reason I mean that I just can't look at $\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty c_{i,j}$ as a rearrangment is that if we did, we would never get past i=1?

Answer (score 0):

For each $j\in \Bbb N$, $c_{i,j} \le b_i$ for all $i\in \Bbb N$. So for each $N$, $$\sum_{i = 1}^N c_{i,j} \le \sum_{i = 1}^N b_i \le \sum_{i = 1}^\infty b_i$$ for all $j\in \Bbb N$. Therefore, for each $j\in \Bbb N$, the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty c_{i,j}$ are bounded. As the terms $c_{i,j}$ are nonnegative, this implies that $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty c_{i,j}$ converges for all $j\in \Bbb N$. Since

$$\sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{j = 1}^\infty c_{i,j} = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \sum_{i = 1}^N c_{i,j} \le \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \sum_{i = 1}^\infty c_{i,j}$$ for all $N\in \Bbb N$, the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty b_i$ are bounded, which implies $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty b_i$ converges and $$\sum_{i = 1}^\infty\sum_{j = 1}^\infty c_{i,j} \le \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \sum_{i = 1}^\infty c_{i,j}.$$ Switching the roles of $i$ and $j$, we may deduce the reverse inequality

$$\sum_{j = 1}^\infty \sum_{i = 1}^\infty c_{i,j} \le \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 1}^\infty c_{i,j}.$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{i = 1}^\infty b_i = \sum_{i= 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 1}^\infty c_{i,j} = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \sum_{i = 1}^\infty c_{i,j}.$$